# EF query builder

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework

I have a list of ids which i have to search in database table.

i have a employee table where employee id is primary key.
and I have a list of employee id that i have to search in this employee table

I am using EF 6.1.1, SQL 2012.

Here is my code snippet

```
 using (var ctx = new NORTHWNDContext())
        {
            var eId = new int[] { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
            var r = ctx.Employees.
                Join(ctx.Orders,
                        e => e.EmployeeID,
                        o => o.EmployeeID,
                        (e, o) => new { Employee = e, Order = o }
                    )
                    .Where(p => eId.Contains(p.Employee.EmployeeID));
            var es = ctx.Employees;
            foreach (var item in r)
            {
                var e = item.Employee;
                var o = item.Order;
            }
        }
```

When EF build the query and pass to database
as below

```
SELECT
[Extent1].[EmployeeID] AS [EmployeeID],
[Extent1].[ReportsTo] AS [ReportsTo],
[Extent1].[PhotoPath] AS [PhotoPath],
[Extent2].[OrderID] AS [OrderID],
FROM  [dbo].[Employees] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Orders] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[EmployeeID] = [Extent2]
```

.[EmployeeID]
    WHERE [Extent1].[EmployeeID] IN (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

EF query builder (expression builder) is not enough intelligent by default to understand these are the duplicate values and use one unique value.

Right now i did filtering at list before passing this to

```
.Where(p => eId.Contains(p.Employee.EmployeeID));
```

This solve the issue. but code changes will be on multiple places and not easy to maintenance.

But I would like to solve this issue at EF level.

Note :- i use simple query to explain my problem. but in real project my query is huge and database size is large.

Comment: I think the database engine is smart enough to optimize this query. (Sql Server is). So don't worry. But what's so hard about making `eId` distinct first?

Comment: yeah i can make distict id list before passing but this is overhead, i have to make sure every time. also one more this if i do like this   .Where(p => eId.Distinct().Contains(p.Employee.EmployeeID)); this create a union in SQL query and this fails in large employee id list.

Comment: SQL server is not smart enough to optimize the query in this case.. i tried with multiple similar id list this took 9 ms to process where as for distinct it took less than 3 ms. ( need to cosider expression build time and sql query execution time).

Comment: Yes, that's correct, the time to build the expression will increase with the number of elements. Well, make Distinct is all I can say. EF is what it is. We can't propose change requests here.